# Wildcard link for user menu

Tags: routes, users

I have a dropping menu links for the user menu:

My account

- Profile edit
- My posts (track)
- Exit

Here's an example of my code:

```
  <ul id="userNavigation">
                <li><?php echo l(t("Profile edit"), "user/%/edit"); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo l(t("My posts"), "user/%/track"); ?></li>
                <li class="exit"><?php echo l(t("Exit"), "user/logout"); ?></li>
            </ul>
```

I've tried with wildcard %. With a Views module was very easy, but in this case (without views) it's not working. 
Is any other way so when user clicks on "My posts" will link to `user/user_id/track` or profile edit that will lead to `user/user_id/edit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use menu wildcards like that. You need to use the following code.

```
  <ul id="userNavigation">
    <li><?php echo l(t("Profile edit"), 'user/' . $GLOBALS['user']->uid . '/edit'); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo l(t("My posts"), 'user/' . $GLOBALS['user']->uid . '/track'); ?></li>
    <li class="exit"><?php echo l(t("Exit"), "user/logout"); ?></li>
  </ul>
```

The global `$user` is the user object for the currently logged-in user. Be careful: It is not a fully-loaded user object. If you need that, you should use the value returned from [user_uid_optional_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_uid_optional_load/7).

Comment: Thank you very much, It's working perfectly! Also thanks for notice!